# slnx.sqlite and .csproj files causing merge conflict in DevOps

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

There are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160735/trying-to-undo-ignore-by-adding-slnx-sqlite-file-in-git-ignore-file-in-visual-s) questions to this, but I'm pretty new to Git (long-serving TFS user) and am struggling with this.  I am nervous about applying the ideas suggested by others without a full understanding of what's actually going on...

After branching/merging successfully for a few months, today the following two merge conflicts are shown when I try to merge a working branch into the main one when creating a pull request:

```
2 merge conflicts
slnx.sqlite              Edited in both
My Web Site MVC.csproj   Edited in both
```

[image]

I haven't (consciously) edited these files, so don't understand why they are showing and cannot be merged.  I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and it doesn't appear to show any conflicts (that I can see or figure out).

I'd be very grateful for the following please:

1. An explanation into why these files are suddenly showing, but haven't previously?
2. How to fix the conflicts in either VS or DevOps portal (I've seen a guide for both but am seeing different options/functionality that the guides demonstrate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An explanation into why these files are suddenly showing, but haven't previously?

Select "Files" from the pictures you post. You can see what changes were made to the conflicting files here.

[image]

> How to fix the conflicts in either VS or DevOps portal?

You can use a Microsoft extension called [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab&ssr=false#overview). With this extension, you can know where the files of the two branches conflict, and you can manually edit what you choose to keep.

**Update**:

I found [a link](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues/237) that might describe why the `slnx.sqlite file` appears. Here is the content of the link:

> Currently slnx.sqlite is part of the tracked files. It was probably added by mistake before .gitignore was added. It updates automatically by VS and thus prevent some Git commands from executing since they require all tracked files to be in the unmodified state.

Comment: The `slnx.sqlite` file sadly couldn't be viewed but taking the Source branch solved the issue anyway as I knew that was the most recent.  That extension was the perfect solution for the `.csproj` conflict.  I don't suppose there's any reason why that isn't installed by default when it is so useful?

Comment: @EvilDr I am glad that my answer can help you solve the issue! Also, I just found a link and updated my answer.