# how to remove a file from git to never exist at all

Tags: git, laravel-5, gitlab

so i pushed a `ouath key file` into my git branch from my local copy. how do i overwrite commits in git to remove the `oauth key file`?

i tried doing

`git rm cache /storage/oauth.key` and did a git add, git commit, git push to my branch but the file is still there.

i also tried doing

`git revert commitID`  but got an error

`error: commit 5ac87ad863059396jkljkljlkjce4c64 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed`

please advice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188613/7976758

Answer (score 1):

try

`git rm --cached storage/oauth.key`

then add your deleted oauth key file on stage, commit and push.
This must delete the key file from your remote repository.