# Fail to push to github because a file committed before exceeds 100MB

Tags: git, github

Once there was a file that exceeds 100MB in my project and I committed it. After a long time and some other commits, I wanted to push to remote repository in github. However, I met the error "a file exceeds limited size of github(100MB) though I have deleted the file when I push.

I've seen some of the answers to similar problems, suggesting giving up recent commits. But this is not practical since there have been a lot of commits. Is there any better way?

Comment: use the command git reset --hard

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history

Answer (score 0):

try using an hard reset

use the command

```
git reset --hard

git rebase -i
```