# Reduce size of .git and clear from history with removing accidentally pushed files

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed and pushed some binary files to origin/master. I figured out my mistake and `git rm -f MASSIVE.FILES` and commit/push ed again. Now, for cloning a 5KB project, it needs to download few hundred mega bytes because those deleted files are still in history.

The question is, how can I remove those massive files completely from history (.git)?

I already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872700/2473837), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/308684/2473837) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17100265/2473837) but none of them helped me.

Comment: In what way existing answers don't help?

Comment: @phd It still downloads all files including those `git rm -f`ed file and put them in .git directory. So download size is the same although massive files are removed completely.

Comment: The accepted answer in the first link talks about `git filter-branch`. It should help in your case.