# How do I avoid a Github push error

Tags: git, github

When I do a push to GitHub I get an error that one particular file (tv.zip) is too big. I deleted this file from my local directory and then committed that change. I no longer want to save that file.

Then I did a push again and I get the same error about the same file that I already deleted from the local directory.

What do I need to do so that I can push. Below is the text of what is happening:

```
c:\Users\rplaza\Files\GitHub\Documents>git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

 nothing to commit, working directory clean

c:\Users\rplaza\Files\GitHub\Documents>git push
Counting objects: 127, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (106/106), done.
Writing objects: 100% (118/118), 665.07 MiB | 264.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 118 (delta 37), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (37/37), completed with 6 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large 
File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: b39c9ffdfb91284e9d625110da8b559f
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File ThirdParty/DVSI Voice Codec/DVSI Files - Older/tv.zip is 
593.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/Revcord/documents.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://github.com/Revcord/documents.git'
```

Comment: did you typed git add -A and then git commit -m"Removing file" ? After removing the file

Comment: That file may be in your commit history that you are trying to push (5 commits you are trying to push). Removing it in your last commit does not remove it from previous commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)