# Remove specific changes from previous commit

Tags: git

I have made couple of commits to my branch and pushed it to the remote.
I didnt notice some unwanted files were added/modified and they were commited as well in one of the first commits.
Is it possible to remove only those changes? (only the unwanted files)

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't exactly store *files*.  Instead, Git stores *commits* (and then the commits have files).

Git is very much oriented towards *adding new commits*.  You can add new commits in which the files are not present.  This means that whenever you check out the *old* commit, the file *is* present—it gets added to your work-tree—and then whenever you switch to the *new* commit, the file gets *removed*.  (Would you say that this file is, or is not, in the repository?  Why, or why not?)

If that's sufficient, simply remove the unwanted file(s) with `git rm`, commit the result, and push the new commits to add them to the upstream version of the repository.  The newest commit now does not have the file(s).  Since checking out a branch checks out the newest commit that is the tip of that branch, `git checkout <whatever-branch>` will give you a work-tree that does not have the file(s).  But the files *are* still in the older commits.

If that's *not* sufficient, see the linked possible-duplicate.